# The arrow in the PDF-Tools viewer disappears too quickly when using the 'pdf-sync-forward-search' command in a LaTeX document

Tags: latex, init-file, auctex, pdf-tools, previewing

Occasionally the arrow does persist long enough to see it in the PDF output, but usually it flashes by too quickly to even detect it.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

It took me several hours of reading through newsgroup postings to get pdf-tools working at all, and while some of that initially had to do with the quirkiness of msys2, I still feel that the package could use better out-of-the-box default settings.